# Replace light Switch with Zwave light switch

Tags: switch

I have two light switches which control the same light (is this known as a 3way connection?).  I would like to replace one of the switches with a Z-wave light switch so I can incorporate the light in some home automation scenes.

Can I do this by just replacing one of the existing light switches with a Z-wave enabled one? Do I need to look for a special 3-way Z-Wave light switch? Do such things exist?

I am handy, but definitely not an electrician.

Here is a picture of how the switch is currently wired:

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch boxes please?

Comment: Yeah, I think you will need a switch that can work in a 3-way circuit for the other light switch to continue working.

Comment: @ArchonOSX -- if he can get us photos of the boxes, I can likely tell if he has a neutral at the switch or not.  If he has a neutral at the switch, then he could use a single-pole Z-wave light switch to control a SPDT relay ;)

Comment: I will post photos next weekend. Sorry about the delay on the photos, but I get home after 6pm on weekdays and it is too dark with the breaker off to take pictures.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel as requested a photo has been added.  Looking forward to what you guys have to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your 3-way switch install isn't compatible with Z-wave switches -- even if a 3-way Z-wave switch existed, all the Z-wave devices I know of require a neutral to function, and you don't have that.  Instead, you have an old-style switch loop where the white wire is retagged to be a traveler, hot, or switched hot instead of a neutral.

Comment: Unfortunately, not the answer I was looking for, but I appreciate the input.

Comment: Can you explain what you see that shows it's a switched hot?

Comment: @SamRueby -- what I know for sure is that that white wire *can't* be a neutral (since it's connected to an old-school lightswitch)